# Get clicked button on lostfocus event

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have an UWP application which have a series of buttons with a click event. I also have a textbox that I need to keep focus on almost every click/touch on the app. So I set a resetFocus function like this:

```
public void resetfocus2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Username.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
}
```

that triggers on every click outside this textbox.

This is the button in the XAML

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="4" Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Tag="{Binding id}" Grid.Column="0" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="100" Background="White" Click="Meal1_Click">
                        <Image Width="100" Height="100" Source="{Binding idImg}" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" />
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**My Question is:**

How can I call the function normally called with the button click inside of this function ?

Since the lostfocus event happens before the click and the click function is never triggered.

UPDATE:
This is the code that create the dialog from the button:

```
public async void Meal1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ServiziSoapClient service = new ServiziSoapClient();
        var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        var mealresponse = await service.SERVICE("PASSWORD", (sender as Button).Tag.ToString(), (string)localSettings.Values["stabilimento"]);

        var response = JsonValue.Parse(mealresponse.Body.SERVICE).GetObject();

        var notnull = 0;
        try
        {
            var temp = response.GetNamedArray("OPTION");
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception " + exc.Message);
            notnull = 1;
        }

        JsonArray allergeni = null;
        var piatto = response.GetNamedObject("OPTION2");
        if (notnull == 0)
            allergeni = response.GetNamedArray("OPTION");

        var ingredienti = response.GetNamedString("OPTION3");

        var btn = sender as Button;
        var dialog = new ContentDialog()
        {
            Title = piatto.GetNamedString("descr"),
            //RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Dark,
            //FullSizeDesired = true,
            MaxWidth = this.ActualWidth // Required for Mobile!
        };

        // Setup Content
        var panel = new StackPanel();

        var defaultImageUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/ic_placeholder_primi.png");
        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.ImageFailed += (s, ex) => bitmap.UriSource = defaultImageUri;
        bitmap.UriSource = new Uri("http://test-wsmensa.sinergest.it//WS/getImage.ashx?GETIN=B&&@pp2015Gi@BoS&ID_IMMAGINE=" + piatto.GetNamedNumber("idImg") + "&HEIGHT=100", UriKind.Absolute);

        panel.Children.Add(new Image
        {
            Height = 400,
            Width = 400,
            Source = bitmap
        });


        panel.Children.Add(new TextBlock
        {
            TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap,
            FontSize = 20,
            Text = "Ingredienti: " + ingredienti
        });
        dialog.Content = panel;

        dialog.PrimaryButtonText = "Chiudi";
        // Show Dialog
        var result = await dialog.ShowAsync();
        UserName.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if UWP has this too, but in regular WPF I'd just set `Focusable = "False"` on the buttons. That way your textbox should never lose focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want the buttons won't get focus when you click or tap the buttons. If so you can set [`IsTabStop` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.istabstop.aspx) to `false`to make buttons cannot receive input focus.

> If **IsTabStop** is **false**, the control is excluded from tab navigation. In addition, if **IsTabStop** is **false**, the control cannot receive input focus. (If you try to set focus programmatically, by calling the **[Focus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh702161.aspx)** method, **Focus** returns **false**).

So you can change your XAML code like:

```
<Button IsTabStop="False" Tag="{Binding id}" Grid.Column="0" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="100" Background="White" Click="Meal1_Click">
```

After this, the buttons won't get foucs and if your textbox has got focus, it will keep focus when users click or tap on the buttons.

Comment: perfect. Exactly what I was looking for!